# Showing $f(x) \geq 2f(\frac{u+v}{2})-f(\frac{u+v}{2}-t)$ for $f$ convex

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation, convex-analysis

consider a convex function $f$ on a compact subinterval $[u,v]$.

write an arbitrary point $x\in [u,v]$ as $x=(u+v)/2+t$ for some $t$ with $\vert t\vert \leq (v-u)/2$.

Then $f(x)=f(\frac{u+v}{2}+t)$, but how to go from here to

$$
f(x)=f(\frac{u+v}{2}+t)\geq 2f(\frac{u+v}{2})-f(\frac{u+v}{2}-t)
$$

Im sure it follows from writing $\frac{u+v}{2}+t$ as $2\frac{u+v}{2} - (\frac{u+v}{2}-t)$ and then somehow doing a convex combination, and using the definition of convexity. I don't see what convex combination works though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac{u+v}{2} = \frac 12 \left(  \left(\frac{u+v}{2} - t \right) + \left(\frac{u+v}{2} + t \right) \right)   
$$
implies for the convex function $f$ that
$$
f\left(\frac{u+v}{2}\right) \le \frac 12 \left(  f\left(\frac{u+v}{2} - t \right) + f\left(\frac{u+v}{2} + t \right) \right)   
$$

Comment: I see. I was trying to expand $(u+v)/2 +t$. Thank you.